# Can i insert Bytecode inside my source code?

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation

Can i write bytecode inside a method of a class so that the compiler bypasses that part since it is already compiled. Something similar to writing assembly programs in C language using "asm"...

Comment: You should also look for bytecode manipulation libraries like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) and [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do this? Your Java bytecode isn't ran on the target processor directly, it will either be interpreted or recompiled into native machine code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean Java. If that's the case:

Short answer: **no**.

Long answer:
There is nothing like `asm { ... }` in Java. But you *could* (not very clever in most situations) write a `.class` file (or have bytecode in textual representation and then assemble it in Java to a `.class` file) from Java and dynamically load and execute it.

Comment: You said... "(or have bytecode in textual representation and then assemble it in Java to a .class file)"...can you give more inputs on this...

Comment: Sure, you store the textual bytecode representation (as `javap -c SomeJavaClass` outputs it) as a `String` in your Java source. While your program is running, you can assemble that code(e.g. with Jasmin (http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/)) which gives you a `.class` file. That class can be loaded dynamically with the class loader. Finally, you can execute anything from that class.